# How to display data dynamically with ant design tables

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, django, antd

first please my javascript skill level is not good, but here... I have a table i got from ant.design, im trying to build a frontend with react, so I want to display some data on the table from my database but im finding it had because of the want ant design table is set up.

This is the code

```
class OrderSummary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchOrder();
  }

  handleFetchOrder = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    authAxios
      .get(orderSummaryURL)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data, loading: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // if (err.response.status === 404) {
        //   this.setState({
        //     error: "You currently do not have an order",
        //     loading: false
        //   });
        // } else {
          this.setState({ error: err, loading: false });
        // }
      });
  };

    render() {
      const columns = [
        {
          title: 'Number',
          dataIndex: 'number',
          key: 'number',
          render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
        },
        {
          title: 'Event Name',
          dataIndex: 'name',
          key: 'name',
        },
        {
          title: 'Event Price',
          dataIndex: 'price',
          key: 'price',
        },
        {
          title: 'Quantity',
          dataIndex: 'quantity',
          key: 'quantity',
        },
        {
          title: 'Total',
          dataIndex: 'total',
          key: 'total',
        },
      
      ];

      const datasource = 
        {data.order_items.map((orderItem, i) => {
        return (
          [
              {
                key: {orderItem.id},
                number: {orderItem.item.title} -{" "},
                name: 32,
                price: 'NGN' {orderItem.item.price} ,
                quantity: {orderItem.quantity},
                total: {data.total},
                
              },
              // {
              //   key: 1,
              //   name: 'John Brown',
              //   age: 32,
              //   address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
              //   tags: ['nice', 'developer'],
              // },
      ];

        return (
            <Layout>
            <div>
                 <PageHeader
                    className="site-page-header"
                    onBack={() => null}
                    title="Order Summary"
                />
                <Table columns={columns} 
                
                dataSource={datasource} />
            </div>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
};

export default OrderSummary;
```

Note where i commented out, that part works perfectly because thats how it comes from ant.design

This is the error I keep getting

```
Failed to compile
./src/containers/OrderSummary.js
  Line 95:14:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  93 | 
  94 |       const datasource = 
> 95 |         {data.order_items.map((orderItem, i) => {
     |              ^
  96 |         return (
  97 |           [
  98 |               {
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

It seems you didn't close correctly your `datasource`.

After your `]`  you need  `) } ) } ;`

### Second

You have to add `order_items` in `data` in the `state`, as it's null and `handleFetchOrder` is asynchronous. At the time you want to render it will create an error because you try to iterate over a no existing property.

#### Here a example of what you can try:

**In your state declaration:**

```
state = {
      data: {
          order_items: []
      },
      error: null,
      loading: false
};
```

**In your render function:**

Add a const to get your state value:

```
const data = this.state.data;
const datasource = { data.order_items.map((orderItem, i) => { ... })};
```

Comment: Where does come from `data` ?
There are no props, properties or function with this name in your code.

Comment: I have edited the question, please check and advice.

Comment: You have to set `data` as an object with an empty array property of the name `order_items`.